# Filtering elements inside an array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have this JSON and would like to filter by `WHERE installmentType = 'STANDARD'`

In the SELECT clause I would like to return the region attribute.

```
{
    "processedResult": {
        "TYPE": "ACKNOWLEDGEMENT",
        "orderPayment": {
            "paymentDetails": [
                {
                    "installmentPayment": {
                        "installmentType": "STANDARD"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "region": "US"
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

| region | type |
| --- | --- |
| US | ACKNOWLEDGEMENT |

What I've tried so far but this just gives me the `paymentDetails` block:

```
SELECT arr.item_object
FROM aosqe_ema_tools.ocs_response t,
jsonb_array_elements(t.ocsjsonb -> 'processedResult' -> 'orderPayment' -> 'paymentDetails') 
with ordinality arr(item_object, position)
```

Postgres Version : PostgreSQL 11.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `item_object` in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
select 
  ocsjsonb -> 'processedResult' ->> 'region' as region,
  ocsjsonb -> 'processedResult' ->> 'TYPE' as type
from ocs_response
cross join jsonb_array_elements(
  ocsjsonb -> 'processedResult' -> 'orderPayment' -> 'paymentDetails') 
    as arr(item_object)
where item_object -> 'installmentPayment' ->> 'installmentType' = 'STANDARD'
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/HVzUAAwf)